# ActiveRecord counter_cache increments db but not instance

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rspec2, ruby-1.9.3, counter-cache

I have two simple classes `Company` and `Votings` which I test with rspec.

When I add a voting to a company it gets counted by an activeRecord

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :votings_count
  has_many :votings, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

and this voting class:

```
class Voting < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :percent, :company, :company_id

  belongs_to :company, counter_cache: true
end
```

and this simple rspec

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Company do   
  it "should count the votings in a table" do
   c = Company.new(Fabricate.attributes_for :company)
   c.save
   c.votings.create(Fabricate.attributes_for :voting)
   c.votings_count.should == 1
  end
end
#expected: 1
#got: 0 (using ==)
```

the column is not nil. Default = 0

```
add_column :companies, :votings_count, :integer, default: 0
```

I've followed the example from ryans counter_cache cast -> http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column?view=asciicast

The DB is counted correctly, but the instance is not updated.

**Do I have a wrong setup?
Why do this behave like this?**

many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reload the instance to reflect the changes in db.

```
# ...
c.save
c.votings.create(Fabricate.attributes_for :voting)
# Add this line
c.reload
c.votings_count.should == 1
```

Comment: Not, this is not cool! Because reload make a query to db (which is unnecessary). It should update automatically in associated instance.